# I want to split data in R by varying block sizes but each observation is unique

Tags: r

I have managed to read in a data file, and subset out the 2 columns of info that I want to work with. I am now stuck because I need to split the data into chunks of varying sizes and apply a function (mean, sd) to them, save the chunks and plot the sd from each. Otherwise known generally as block averaging. Right now I have a data frame with 2 columns and 10005 rows. The head of it looks like this:

```
Frame    CA
    1 0.773
```

Is there an efficient way that I could subset pieces of the data from a:b so that I can dictate how the data is broken up by the "Frame" column? I have found really good answers on here but I am not sure what they mean fully or if they would work.

```
chunk <- function(x, n) 
(mapply(function(a, b) (x[a:b]), seq.int(from=1, to=length(x), by=n), 
      pmin(seq.int(from=1, to=length(x), by=n)+(n-1), 
          length(x)), SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
```

Comment: Have you looked at `tapply()`?

Comment: It's not clear what the interplay is between (1) the requirement of grouping your data.frame into fixed-length "blocks"/"chunks" and (2) the natural grouping of the data.frame by the `Frame` column. Do you care which Frames get pulled into which blocks? Do you want to compute the mean and sd separately for each Frame within each block? Or just once for the entire block, regardless of Frames?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is what you're looking for but with closure, a data frame can be subsetted by arbitrary indices.

(If `Frame` can be subsetted by `a:b`, it is likely to be a sequence and thus a subset may be made by row index?)

```
df <- data.frame(group = sample(c("a", "b"), 20, replace = T),
                 val = rnorm(20))

# closure - returns a function that accepts from and to
subsetter <- function(from, to) {
    function(x) {
        x[from:to, ]
    }
}

# from and to are specified
sub1 <- subsetter(2, 4)
sub2 <- subsetter(1, 5)

# data is split from to to
sub1(df)
#group        val
#2     a  0.5518802
#3     b  1.5955093
#4     a -0.8132578

sub2(df)
#  group        val
#1     b  0.4780080
#2     a  0.5518802
#3     b  1.5955093
#4     a -0.8132578
#5     b  0.4449554
```